# CLR Method Hooking

Tags: .net, c++-cli, hook, clr

I want to hook a CLR Method, in my case I tried to hook AppDomain->Load(byte[]).

I tried several examples I could find to hook self written class methods, but none of them seemed to work for CLR methods. So I tried to stick with a vtable hook of the AppDomain::CurrentDomain object, which seems to work in theory.
However, whenever it calls my method, it somewhere crashes inside and WinDBG displays the following error:

`ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
Attempt to execute non-executable address 000000d801020200
Stack:
00000000001aece0 000007fe927e20da cppclihook!DomainBoundILStubClass.IL_STUB_ReversePInvoke+0x8a
00000000001aee10 000007fe927e1a28 cppclihook!_Module_.main+0x48
00000000001aef20 000007fe927e1988 cppclihook!DomainBoundILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke+0x68`

I got the vtable offset by simply calling AppDomain->Load and checking the generated disassembly code in vs, which can be seen here:

[image: disassembly of AppDomain->Load call]

The current code:

```
public delegate Reflection::Assembly^ CurrentDomain_LoadDelegate_Hook(AppDomain^ thisptr, array<uint8_t>^ data);
public delegate Reflection::Assembly^ CurrentDomain_LoadDelegate(array<uint8_t>^ data);
Reflection::Assembly^ (__clrcall* CurrentDomain_Load)(AppDomain^ thisptr, array<uint8_t>^ data);

Reflection::Assembly^ __clrcall CurrentDomain_Load_Hook(AppDomain^ thisptr, array<uint8_t>^ data)
{
System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show("Hooked");

// calls jmp <clr.AssemblyNative::LoadImage>
return CurrentDomain_Load(thisptr, data);
}

void HookDomain(AppDomain^ domain)
{
    auto fp = gcnew CurrentDomain_LoadDelegate_Hook(CurrentDomain_Load_Hook);
    RuntimeHelpers::PrepareMethod(fp->Method->MethodHandle);

    auto gch = GCHandle::Alloc(fp);
    auto ip = Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(fp);
    auto hookAddr = (uintptr_t)ip.ToPointer();

    // auto orig = gcnew CurrentDomain_LoadDelegate(domain, &AppDomain::Load);
    // RuntimeHelpers::PrepareMethod(orig->Method->MethodHandle);

    auto domainPtrHandle = System::Runtime::InteropServices::GCHandle::Alloc(domain);
    auto domainIntPtr = System::Runtime::InteropServices::GCHandle::ToIntPtr(domainPtrHandle);
    auto domainPtr = *(uintptr_t*)domainIntPtr.ToPointer();

    auto vtableAddr = *(uintptr_t***)domainPtr;
    auto funcAddr = vtableAddr[12];

    DWORD protect;
    VirtualProtect(funcAddr, sizeof(uintptr_t), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &protect);
    // save orig addr
    // CurrentDomain_Load = ?
    *funcAddr = hookAddr;
    VirtualProtect(funcAddr, sizeof(uintptr_t), protect, &protect);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    HookDomain(AppDomain::CurrentDomain);

    try
    {
        array<uint8_t>^ arr = gcnew array<uint8_t>(256);
        System::AppDomain::CurrentDomain->Load(arr);
    }
    catch(Exception^) {}

    return 0;
}
```

I actually checked what's happening inside the original Load method, and it doesn't seem to do anything special:

[image: AppDomain->Load call]
[image: Call of Load call]

When I'm following my hook method from the vtable call, it crashes here when calling an invalid pointer:

[image: invalid RBX]

I also tried to give a native DLL the AppDomain pointer and hook to a native function which simply calls the original address.
Since it only generates a JMP [original_load] I hoped that would work, but it starts to crash somewhere in the NET call.

Am I missing something, or what am I doing wrong?
Hopefully anyone can help me.

Comment: `Assembly.Load` is **not** virtual, therefore there's no vtable entry for it. I'm pretty sure you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271659) here - what are you actually trying to achieve?